# When using SkiaSharp SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode is it possible to create a dashed line?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, skiasharp, skia

I'm using CreateBlendMode to change the color of an SVG drawing as follows:

```
public Color TintColor;
TintColor = Colors.LawnGreen;

using (var paint = new SKPaint())
{
   paint.ColorFilter = SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(SKColor.Parse(TintColor.ToHex()), 
   SKBlendMode.SrcIn);
   canvas.DrawPicture(Picture, position.X, position.Y, paint);
}
```

Image before

[image]

Image after

[image]

But I need the line to be dashed like the next image. It is possible?

[image]

Comment: Which platform do you test on? For the android, the `PathEffect` needs some changes and you can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/dots).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Just set the PathEffect of the paint you are using.

Example:

```
SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();
paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
paint.StrokeWidth = 1.5f;
SKRect rect = new SKRect(_MouseDownPt.X, _MouseDownPt.Y, _MouseMovePt.X, _MouseMovePt.Y);
paint.PathEffect = SKPathEffect.CreateDash(new float[] {10,6},0);
paint.Color = new SKColor(0xaa,0x40,0);
paint.BlendMode = SKBlendMode.ColorDodge;
canvas.DrawRect(rect,paint);
```

Comment: Hi!  I tried like this:
`
SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();
paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
paint.StrokeWidth = 1.5f;
paint.PathEffect = SKPathEffect.CreateDash(new float[] { 5, 5 }, 10);
paint.ColorFilter = SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(SKColors.LawnGreen, SKBlendMode.SrcIn);
canvas.DrawPicture(Picture, position.X, position.Y, paint);
`
But the result is the same as the second image. Change color but no dashed stroke